# Tone.js release/stop sampler

Tags: javascript, release, web-audio-api, envelope, tonejs

EDIT: Update on other attempts. The key bit of the question below is the line `sampler.triggerRelease(["A1"], 'now')` which is not working. Other things I've tried include:

- `sampler.releaseAll(Tone.now())`
- `sampler.releaseAll()`
- `sampler.triggerRelease(["A1"], Tone.now())`

The relevant part of the Tone.js docs is [here](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Sampler.html).

What won't work is `sampler.dispose()`, because it essentially disconnects the sampler instrument from the output. But I need to continue using the sampler to retrigger the same note shortly after turning it off.

---

I'm trying to use a button press to stop the playing of a 'Sampler' note while it's currently playing. I thought that triggering the release phase would do this (as in my code below) but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I've tried lots of methods. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994325/tone-js-completely-stop-all-playing-sounds) doesn't answer mine, partly because it's for the 'Polysynth' not the 'Sampler'. Thanks in advance!

```js
const readyOverlay = document.querySelector('#readyOverlay')
readyOverlay.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    readyOverlay.style.display = 'none'
    await Tone.start()

    const sampler = new Tone.Sampler({
        urls: {
            A1: "A1.mp3"
        },
        baseUrl: "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/casio/",
        onload: () => {
            sampler.triggerAttackRelease(["A1"], 5);
        }
    }).toDestination();
    sampler.release = 0
    document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
        sampler.triggerRelease(["A1"], 'now')
    })
})
```

```css
        #readyOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tone@14.7.77/build/Tone.js"></script>
    <div id="readyOverlay">Press anywhere to start!</div>
    <button id="stop" >stop</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `triggerAttackRelease` with just `triggerAttack` does work:

```js
const readyOverlay = document.querySelector('#readyOverlay')
readyOverlay.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    readyOverlay.style.display = 'none'
    await Tone.start()

    const sampler = new Tone.Sampler({
        urls: {
            A1: "A1.mp3"
        },
        baseUrl: "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/casio/",
        onload: () => {
            sampler.triggerAttack(["A1"]);
        }
    }).toDestination();
    sampler.release = 0;
    document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
        sampler.triggerRelease(["A1"]);
    })
})
```

```css
        #readyOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tone@14.7.77/build/Tone.js"></script>
    <div id="readyOverlay">Press anywhere to start!</div>
    <button id="stop" >stop</button>
```

`triggerAttackRelease` is just a sequence of `triggerAttack` and `triggerRelease` calls. It means you have already scheduled a note release in the `onload` callback in your initial example.

Tone.js ignores the second release call because `sampler` has already marked "A1" as released ([this `if` statement makes sure note is released only once after the attack](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/blob/b91b34d79293a7504f1dfc1552bfd4223dc2bb61/Tone/instrument/Sampler.ts#L229-L236)).